Issue in spring boot 2.7.6 returning NoHandlerException for GET '/v3/test/'
I am using spring boot 2.7.6, Gradle 8.6 and here is the application.properties file
spring.mvc.servlet.path = /v3
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found = true
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/documents/**
spring.web.resources.static-locations = classpath:/public/documents/

I have controller mapping as below
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test)
public class test{
    
    ....
}

So not sure why i am getting this error on the server .
I have Tried adding new SecurityFilterChain and webSecurityCustomizer as well in the project. As WebSecurityConfigureAdapter is deprecated in spring boot 2.7.6

Adding Spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ant_path_matcher will fix the issue.
